# C# Detect Desktop Folder Mouse-Up during a Drag operation?

Tags: c#, winapi, desktop, directory, drag-and-drop

*< I have reviewed the "related questions" shown by SO before posting this >*

Scenario :

1. Drag and drop initiated from a control within a WinForm.

   *note : all drag and drop code validated, carefully tested. I can use the code right now
   to create/write a file to the Desktop when the mouse is released.*
2. Drag goes outside the Form, mouse goes up over the Desktop or some "item" on the Desktop.

[edit in response to comment by Groo]

In this case the drop may go onto the desktop (where it will become a file : that case is already handled); or, the drop may go into a control of the same type (as the control from which the drag was initiated) in another application's running instance (that case is taken care of). The case that I am asking about is where the drop occurs on a desktop Folder : Groo's comments have made want to test trying to modify the DataObject type "on the fly" ... during the drag ... which I've never tried before : I have no idea if it's possible.

[end edit ]

I can use the api calls in this code sample [1*] to get an IntPtr ID for the mouse going up over the Desktop : the same IntPtr is returned for any Desktop item, like a Folder, a Shortcut, the Recycle Bin, etc.

What I want is : to be able to detect when the mouse is released over a Folder on the Desktop : of course what I want to do then is to get the path of the folder the mouse went up over : so I can create the file within that folder.

thanks, Bill

[1*]

"FindWindow By Jörg Bausch"

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FindWindow.aspx?msg=3262771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file exists before you start to drag (or you are able to create it before), you can simply specify the source file path in the `DataObject` instance passed to `DoDragDrop` method.

Something like this (you should already have the appropriate handlers):

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.MouseDown += Form1_MouseDown;
    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files = new string[] { @"C:\SomeTestFile.txt" };
        this.DoDragDrop(new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files),
          DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}
```

If you are interested in adding some fancy translucent effects while you are dragging, try [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/adamroot/archive/2008/02/15/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-part-3.aspx). If your file doesn't exist and you really need to create it **after** it has been dropped to explorer, check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DataObjectEx.aspx).

You can also override `DataObject` to handle the `GetData` method which is called when the object is dropped:

```
public class MyDataObject : DataObject
{
    public MyDataObject(string format, object data)
       : base(format, data) { }

    public override object GetData(string format)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Format: "+format);
        return base.GetData(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Groo, I will study the links and code you responded with, and I will add a comment to my post that may clarify why, in this case, I am not putting a file format object into the DataObject. best,